# What's the most cost-effective way to get a group to get their Junior HPR Level 1 certification?

Tags: model-aircraft, rocket

I'm apart of Civil Air Patrol and trying to get other cadets to get their Advanced Rocketry certificates, but the Challenger (Stage V) phase requires a completion of a NAR Junior HPR L1 certification.

If you want to get this through NAR, you have to acquire a paid membership, that is incredibly costly. I looked into getting the certifications through Tripoli, but they don't offer *Junior* HPR L1 certifications, only certifications for individuals that are over 18.

Is there any way we can exploit a membership that can be shared by the squadron, or any other ways we can these certifications by the cheapest means?

I will set a flexible budget of ~100 USD if you have any suggestions.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I hold a NAR cert level 3. I think it would be best if you contacted NAR directly. I am doubtful that you will be able to join/certify as a group. The NAR provides benefits that cost money (most importantly insurance). It sounds like you want the benefits offered by the organization (certification) but do not want to pay full price. You may want to consider the benefits that your cadets will receive by being a member, including the mentoring and personal relationships that come from the rocketry community. It might even lead some of your cadets into the space profession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Tripoli student membership](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ClubExpressClubFiles/795696/documents/Membership_Application_v1.3_144116134.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA6MYUE6DNNNCCDT4J&Expires=1701297035&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DMembership_Application_v1.3.pdf&Signature=%2FQwi6n86YebA%2FU32Ma0dTRVU8qE%3D) is \$20 per year.
A [NAR young senior (21-25) or leader (16-20) membership](https://nar.app.neoncrm.com/np/clients/nar/membershipJoin.jsp) is \$30 per year.

The cheapest (?) L1 motor reload is an Aerotech H128W which you can currently get for \$24. You can share the casing or borrow it from somebody.

Which would leave you with $40-50 to build the rocket. That's not a lot, but doable.

Comment: The rockets and motors are provided and paid for by CAP. I was only basing this off of the cost of getting a certification with no other variables. Thank you for your answer though. Have a great day.